# Как правильно собирать данные формы React из дочернего компонента в родительский без redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Была бы кнопка сабмита, я бы повесил на неё и передал все данные, но так выходить передавать только 1 пару ключ:значение, то есть State заменяется. И да, я знаю, что в потомке стейт не комильфо, однако, как иначе вообще не понимаю. Мне говорили прокинуть пропсы, но те куски кода, что показали, вообще не подходят или не понимаю как сделать.

App.js, родитель

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handlePropChange = this.handlePropChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      filterSet: {}
    }
  }
  handlePropChange(props) {
    this.setState({ filterSet: props })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to CardC</h1>
        </header>
        <Filter onPropChange={this.handlePropChange} />
        {/* <CardList filterSet={this.state.filter} /> */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Код дочернего, Filter.js, из его параметров хочу собрать в App.js, Обработать и передать в CardList

```
class Filter extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleCheck = this.handleCheck.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.state = {
        }
    }
    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.checked ? 1 : 0
        });
    }
    handleCheck(e) {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="filter">
                <div><label>Кешбек&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="cashback" onChange={this.handleCheck} /></label></div>
                <div><label>Бесплатное обслуживание&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="free_price" onChange={this.handleCheck}/></label></div>
                <div><label>Цена&nbsp;<input type="text" name="price" onChange={this.handleChange} /></label></div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ты можешь создать кнопку и к этой кнопке привязать функцию которая через пропс передала бы state твоего дочернего компонента. В state ты можешь добавить конкретные значения. Я сделал пример, но не тестировал его. Тебе скорее всего нужно будет немного изменить то как твой state будет выглядеть. Главное что State это объект, так что с ним по идеи можно делать все (если не все, то многое) что с обычным объектом. Надеюсь это хоть как-то поможет.

```
class Filter extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    name1: '';, 
    name2: ''; 
  }
    this.handleCheck = this.handleCheck.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

}
handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        this.state.name1: e.target.checked ? 1 : 0
    });
}
handleCheck(e) {
    this.setState({
        this.state.name2: e.target.value
    });
}

handleSubmit(event) {
  this.props.onPropChange(this.state.name1, this.state.name2);  
}
render() {
    return (
        <div className="filter">
            <div><label>Кешбек&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="cashback" onChange={this.handleCheck} /></label></div>
            <div><label>Бесплатное обслуживание&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="free_price" onChange={this.handleCheck}/></label></div>
            <div><label>Цена&nbsp;<input type="text" name="price" onChange={this.handleChange} /></label></div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Comment: Спасибо, но с кнопкой я бы даже не спрашивал) вся фишка сделать это на живую,А когда так делаешь, то в this.props.onPropChange отправляется предыдущее значение стейта